# CSS - flex issue

Tags: html, css

Flex container have two sides. Left side have `align-self: flex-end` .

I tried to edit the line-height, but unsuccessfuly.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72gankw3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements are aligned but the `padding` does not allow the text to be aligned:

[image]

just change the `top` `bottom` `padding` in `.item.asfe` like this:

```
.container .item.asfe {
    align-self: flex-end;
    padding: 10px 15px; /*change the vertical padding to more accuracy .*/
}
```

[**Here a fork jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/kxrmosfg/) with the `padding: 10px 15px;`, anyway you can change the vertical padding to achieve more accuracy.